# Add library through cocoapod error in Library

Tags: ios

I am developing an ios.Install Cocoa pods in xcode project and also add library through cocoa pods (AFNetworking)than close project and open work space or run project and show multiple error on library.This Type Of Error Parse Issue-> Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUme_NONNULL_BEGIN',Parse Issue Cannot combine with previous '(Error)'declaration specfier,Parse Issue Expected a type,Parse Issue Expected ')'
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: please list your errors, because there is so many error while installing pods.

Answer (score 0):

year,I am have the same probleam.I think the errors like Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUme_NONNULL_BEGIN'and so on, must depend on xcode 6.4 above.My xcode version is 6.2,I try to update the xcode later.